# Sequential numbering of posts in Tumblr

Tags: tumblr

Is there a *clever* way to have sequential numbering on Tumblr posts? I figured out a way to add JavaScript, by making a Global var in the head (weekNum=0;), then in the relevant section adding:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
w= "<h3>Week " + (weekNum+1) + "</h3>";
weekNum++;
document.write(w);
</script>
```

This works like a charm, except because the posts are generated from the newest to the oldest, the numbering is backwards. What I'm looking for is a way to have my posts numbered "Week 1," "Week 2," etc.

Thanks in advance, all you cleverer than me folks...

Answer (score 0):

You could edit your theme so all of your posts are in a numbered list ie:

```
<ol id="posts">
        {block:Posts}{block:Text}
                <li class="post text">
                    {block:Title}
                        <h3><a href="{Permalink}">{Title}</a></h3>
                    {/block:Title}{Body}
                </li>
            {/block:Text}{block:Photo}
                <li class="post photo">
                    <img src="{PhotoURL-500}" alt="{PhotoAlt}"/>

                    {block:Caption}
                        <div class="caption">{Caption}</div>
                    {/block:Caption}
                </li>
            {/block:Photo}{block:Panorama}
                <li class="post panorama">
                    {LinkOpenTag}
                        <img src="{PhotoURL-Panorama}" alt="{PhotoAlt}"/>
                    {LinkCloseTag}{block:Caption}
                        <div class="caption">{Caption}</div>
                    {/block:Caption}
                </li>
            {/block:Panorama}{block:Photoset}
                <li class="post photoset">
                    {Photoset-500}{block:Caption}
                        <div class="caption">{Caption}</div>
                    {/block:Caption}
                </li>
            {/block:Photoset}{block:Quote}
                <li class="post quote">
                    "{Quote}"

                    {block:Source}
                        <div class="source">{Source}</div>
                    {/block:Source}
                </li>
            {/block:Quote}{block:Link}
                <li class="post link">
                    <a href="{URL}" class="link" {Target}>{Name}</a>

                    {block:Description}
                        <div class="description">{Description}</div>
                    {/block:Description}
                </li>
            {/block:Link}{block:Chat}
                <li class="post chat">
                    {block:Title}
                        <h3><a href="{Permalink}">{Title}</a></h3>
                    {/block:Title}

                    <ul class="chat">
                        {block:Lines}
                            <li class="{Alt} user_{UserNumber}">
                                {block:Label}
                                    <span class="label">{Label}</span>
                                {/block:Label}{Line}
                            </li>
                        {/block:Lines}
                    </ul>
                </li>
            {/block:Chat}{block:Video}
                <li class="post video">
                    {Video-500}{block:Caption}
                        <div class="caption">{Caption}</div>
                    {/block:Caption}
                </li>
            {/block:Video}{block:Audio}
                <li class="post audio">
                    {AudioPlayerBlack}{block:Caption}
                        <div class="caption">{Caption}</div>
                    {/block:Caption}
                </li>
            {/block:Audio}{/block:Posts}
</ol>
```